# Inconsistent standard deviation values using Imagick (PHP) and ImageMagick by CLI

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I created two images, a 3x3 with a white pixel in the center, and a 9x9 with 3x3 white pixels in the center.

Now, evaluating the standard deviation by CLI, the values are:

```
$ identify -verbose nine-white-pixels.png | grep standard 
  standard deviation: 80.498 (0.315678)

$ identify -verbose one-white-pixel.png | grep standard 
  standard deviation: 85 (0.333333)
```

The values are pretty the same.

If I evaluate the SD by Imagick (PHP) for the *same images*, I get:

```
OneWhitePixel: 16384
NineWhitePixels: 3067.905790
```

I dont get why they're both so different and I don't get the pattern. Also, they're so far from the values got through ImageMagick (CLI).

Can you please help me to find out how does it work?

Comment: Post your images. We need to know what surrounds the white pixels. But the difference is likely that Imagememagick is giving you 8-bit values and the Imagick results are 16-bit values. However, that does not explain fully the values.

Comment: 255*6384/165535=63.75. So 16384 is 16-bits and would correspond to 63.75 when represented as 8-bits as compared to 80.  So I do not understand the difference. Please post your input images or tell us exactly how they were created. What surrounds the white pixels?

Comment: One other difference occurs when the denominator of the std is approx as N and not N-1. This can make a large difference for small N. So if std=63.75 and one used N rather than N-1, one could get 63.75*9/8=71. So still not 80.